# PHP - how to push the result of SimpleXML parsing correctly into the Array?

Tags: php, arrays, xpath, simplexml

I'm trying to push the result of xml parsing to the multidimensional array. The structure of XML is [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72519118/response.xml). The PHP procedure is (not working correctly):

```
$xml_url = simplexml_load_file("url to the xml document");
$data = $xml_url->xpath('MULTIPLE/SINGLE/KEY');

$current = 0;
$topics_list = array();

//display list of 'chapters'
foreach($data as $chap_name) {
    if ($chap_name['name'] == 'name') {
        echo $chap_name->VALUE . '<br />';
        $topics_list[$current]['chapter'] = $chap_name->VALUE;
    }
}

$data2 = $xml_url->xpath('MULTIPLE/SINGLE/KEY[@name="modules"]/MULTIPLE/SINGLE/KEY');

//display list of 'topics' & 'contents'
foreach($data2 as $topic_name) {
    if ($topic_name['name'] == 'name') {
        echo $topic_name->VALUE . '<br />';
        $topics_list[$current]['topic'] = $topic_name->VALUE;
    }
    if ($topic_name['name'] == 'description') {
        echo $topic_name->VALUE . '<br />';
        $topics_list[$current]['content'] = $topic_name->VALUE;
    }
}
print_r($topics_list);
```

The structure of Array in which I want to push the data is:

```
Array (
            [0] => Array (
                    [chapter] => Chapter_name1
                    [name] => Topic_name1
                    [content] => Content_of_the_topic1
                )
            [1] => Array (
                    [chapter] => Chapter_name1
                    [name] => Topic_name2
                    [content] => Content_of_the_topic2
                )
            [2] => Array (
                    [chapter] => Chapter_name2
                    [name] => Topic_name2
                    [content] => Content_of_the_topic2
            )
            .....
        )
```

**UPDATE:** This is the result of above mentioned code proccessing:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(

        [chapter] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => STÖRUNGEN
            )

        [topic] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => 3.25 Starke Blutung
            )

        [content] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [null] => null
                    )
            )
    )
```

)

Comment: In what way is it not working correctly?

Comment: I don't see you incrementing `$current` anywhere. It stays at 0 throughout the loop.

Comment: @Jim See my update... I want just to avoid the **SimpleXMLElement Object** and put all data into the array, now only last values are saved

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I'm new in php and xml parsing, could you advise me, where I need to increment it? thanks

Comment: Wrap the $chap_name->VALUE in get_object_vars() and see if that works.

Michael's comment is to say that you're going to loop through the XML data and thus your topic will Chapter will change, yet you're not increasing $current, thus over-writing it every time. 

With each iteration of Chapter Name you'll need to increase $current

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try 'casting' the value from the SimpleXMLElement to a string when adding it to the array, like this:

```
// add (string) after the '='
$topics_list[$current]['content'] = (string) $topic_name->VALUE;
```

This will make sure the *value* of the SimpleXMLElement element is added as a string, not as a n object.

Also (as marked by others), make sure you increment $current to prevent each record overwriting the previous one

Here's your code updated; But *read the comments in the code*

```
$xml_url = simplexml_load_file("url to the xml document");
$data  = $xml_url->xpath('MULTIPLE/SINGLE/KEY');
$data2 = $xml_url->xpath('MULTIPLE/SINGLE/KEY[@name="modules"]/MULTIPLE/SINGLE/KEY');

$current = 0;
$topics_list = array();

//display list of 'chapters'
foreach($data as $chap_name) {
    if ($chap_name['name'] == 'name') {
        $topics_list[$current]['chapter'] = (string) $chap_name->VALUE;
    }

    // display list of 'topics' & 'contents'
    // NOTE: Not sure if this will work as expected, based on
    //       the name 'topic', I suspect a single chapter
    //       will have *multiple* topics.
    //       Also, those 'topics' will probably need to be 'matched'
    //       to the current 'chapter', so that only the topics for
    //       *this* chapter will be added here!
    foreach($data2 as $topic_name) {
        if ($topic_name['name'] == 'name') {
            $topics_list[$current]['topic'] = (string) $topic_name->VALUE;
        }
        if ($topic_name['name'] == 'description') {
            $topics_list[$current]['content'] = (string) $topic_name->VALUE;
        }
    }

    $current++;
}

print_r($topics_list);
```

Comment: thanks, it works as i want, however i guess i need to put all conditions into one **foreach** loop in order to increment $current correctly. By the way is have you any idea how to do it?

Comment: @Dozent I've updated my answer with a full example, but *read the comments in the code* as I'm not sure this will fully work as expected